# Powershell script not running from batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I've written the following script to add a user to MS Live:

```
$pass = Get-Content D:\PSScripts\pass.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "user@domain.com", $pass
Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred
New-MsolUser -userprincipalname test@domain.com -Displayname "Johny Tester2"
```

I can copy and paste the commands to PowerShell line by line and successfully create a new user, but I can't figure out how to run them all from command line.

I saved the above 4 lines in a file at D:\PSScripts\script2.ps1

I created a file: D:\PSScripts\runall.bat with the following content:

powershell.exe "& 'D:\PSScripts\script2.ps1'"

(I also tried without the & sign, without the quotes, without the 'exe', with -command switch)

It looks like it goes through the first two lines and then it throws and error on 'Connect-MsolService' and 'New-MsolUser':

*The term 'Connect-MsolService' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.*

I need to be able to execute those commands from another program and running a bat file is my best option. Please help.

Running on Win Server 2008 R2, PowerShell Version 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding

```
import-module MSOnline
```

at the start of your `D:\PSScripts\script2.ps1`.

Answer (score 4):

PowerShell 2 doesnt do dynamic module loading, that is however a new feature in PowerShell 3. To fix your issue you can manually import the module into your session using the Import-Module cmdlet. Here's the complete fix.

```
Import-Module MSOnline
$pass = Get-Content D:\PSScripts\pass.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "user@domain.com", $pass
Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred
New-MsolUser -userprincipalname test@domain.com -Displayname "Johny Tester2"
```

Comment: This is a better answer than the one that was accepted because it not only explains what should be done, it explains *why*.

Answer (score 0):

See full topic here: [MSOnline can't be imported on PowerShell (Connect-MsolService error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018732/msonline-cant-be-imported-on-powershell-connect-msolservice-error/16018733#16018733)

What I did to solve the issue was:

Copy the folders called MSOnline and MSOnline Extended from the source

> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\MSOnline

to the folder

> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules

And then in PS run the `Import-Module MSOnline`, and it will automatically get the module :D