# MSOnline can't be imported on PowerShell (Connect-MsolService error)

Tags: windows, powershell, azure, 64-bit, powershell-cmdlet

I had this issue and couldn´t find any answer. The issue was that I was trying to use Azure cdmlets to connect to O365 via c# code, but I couldn´t get the `connect-msolservice`.

> ""The term  is not recognized" error when you try to run administrative Windows PowerShell cmdlets in Office 365"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After hours of searching and trying I found out that on a x64 server the MSOnline modules must be installed for x64, and some programs that need to run them are using the x86 PS version, so they will never find it.

**[SOLUTION]**
What I did to solve the issue was:

Copy the folders called `MSOnline` and `MSOnline Extended` from the source

> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\

to the folder

> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\

And then in PS run the `Import-Module MSOnline`, and it will automatically get the module :D

Comment: Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 61):

After reviewing Microsoft's TechNet article ["Azure Active Directory Cmdlets" -> section "Install the Azure AD Module"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj151815.aspx#sectionSection1), it seems that this process has been drastically simplified, thankfully.

As of 2016/06/30, in order to successfully execute the PowerShell commands `Import-Module MSOnline` and `Connect-MsolService`, you will need to install the following applications (64-bit only):

1. Applicable Operating Systems: Windows 7 to 10
   Name: "Microsoft Online Services Sign-in Assistant for IT Professionals RTW"
   Version: `7.250.4556.0` (latest)
   Installer URL: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41950
   Installer file name: `msoidcli_64.msi`
2. Applicable Operating Systems: Windows 7 to 10
   Name: "Windows Azure Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell"
   Version: Unknown but the latest installer file's SHA-256 hash is `D077CF49077EE133523C1D3AE9A4BF437D220B16D651005BBC12F7BDAD1BF313`
   Installer URL: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn975125.aspx
   Installer file name: `AdministrationConfig-en.msi`
3. Applicable Operating Systems: Windows 7 **only**
   Name: "Windows PowerShell 3.0"
   Version: `3.0` (later versions will probably work too)
   Installer URL: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595
   Installer file name: `Windows6.1-KB2506143-x64.msu`

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thnx for such a nice explanation. Resolved my problem completely.

Comment: Seventeen months later, you still need the BETA version of the Sign-In Assistant (see the Note on step 4). On Win7 x64, I had Sign-In Assistant 7.250.4303 installed so couldn't figure out why Azure setup was complaining that it needed 7.0. Sure enough, after installing Sign-In Assistant BETA 7.250.4551, I was able to install the Azure AD Module.

Comment: The "New Answer" links for #1 and #2 are the same URL.  I believe the corrected link for the Azure Powershell module is in Step #1 here:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn975125.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The solution with copying 32-bit libs over to 64-bit did not work for me. What worked was unchecking Target Platform Prefer 32-bit check mark in project properties.

Comment: Thanks. This fixed my problem when I was trying to run `Connect-MsolService` from within a PowerShell Runspace hosted in my C# app.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a newer version of the SPO Management Shell.  For me to get the error to go away, I changed my Import-Module statement to use:

`Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -DisableNameChecking;`

I also use the newer command:

`Connect-SPOService`

Answer (score 0):

Connects to both Office 365 and Exchange Online in one easy to use script.

REMINDER: You must have the following installed in order to manage Office 365 via PowerShell.

Microsoft Online Services Sign-in Assistant: 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=286152

Azure AD Module for Windows PowerShell 
32 bit - http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=236298 
64 bit - http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=236297

MORE INFORMATION FOUND HERE: 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974317.aspx

Answer (score -2):

The following is needed:

- MS Online Services Assistant needs to be downloaded and installed.
- MS Online Module for PowerShell needs to be  downloaded and installed
- Connect to Microsoft Online in PowerShell

Source: http://www.msdigest.net/2012/03/how-to-connect-to-office-365-with-powershell/

Then
Follow this one if you're running a 64bits computer:
I’m running a x64 OS currently (Win8 Pro).

Copy the folder MSOnline from (1) –> (2) as seen here

1) C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules(MSOnline)

2) C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules(MSOnline)

Source: http://blog.clauskonrad.net/2013/06/powershell-and-c-cant-load-msonline.html

Hope this is better and can save some people's time