# How import modules in Azure webjobs

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-webjobs

I have created C# API (WebApp) and `WebJob` with my `powershell` script in it, but `WebJob` don't work, because script cant import modules that needed to work correctly and throwing following error. Can somebody help me with this trouble? Only possible solution I found is through creation Azure function but it`s not included in my subscription unfortunately.

```
    [05/16/2018 11:30:00 > d69d33: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
    [05/16/2018 11:30:00 > d69d33: SYS INFO] Run script '222.ps1' with script host - 'PowerShellScriptHost'
    [05/16/2018 11:30:00 > d69d33: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
    [05/16/2018 11:30:00 > d69d33: ERR ] Import-Module : The specified module 'MSOnline' was not loaded because no 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:01 > d69d33: ERR ] valid module file was found in any module directory.
    [05/16/2018 11:30:01 > d69d33: ERR ] At D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\TQScheduleSyncWebJob\m2gdbfxu.z4g\222.ps1:1 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:01 > d69d33: ERR ] char:1
    [05/16/2018 11:30:01 > d69d33: ERR ] + Import-Module MSOnline
    [05/16/2018 11:30:01 > d69d33: ERR ] + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    [05/16/2018 11:30:01 > d69d33: ERR ]     + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (MSOnline:String) [Import-M 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:01 > d69d33: ERR ]    odule], FileNotFoundException
    [05/16/2018 11:30:01 > d69d33: ERR ]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comm 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:01 > d69d33: ERR ]    ands.ImportModuleCommand
    [05/16/2018 11:30:01 > d69d33: ERR ]  
    [05/16/2018 11:30:01 > d69d33: ERR ] Import-Module : The specified module 'AzureAD' was not loaded because no valid 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:01 > d69d33: ERR ] module file was found in any module directory.
    [05/16/2018 11:30:01 > d69d33: ERR ] At D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\TQScheduleSyncWebJob\m2gdbfxu.z4g\222.ps1:2 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:01 > d69d33: ERR ] char:1
    [05/16/2018 11:30:01 > d69d33: ERR ] + Import-Module AzureAD
    [05/16/2018 11:30:01 > d69d33: ERR ] + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    [05/16/2018 11:30:01 > d69d33: ERR ]     + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (AzureAD:String) [Import-Mo 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:01 > d69d33: ERR ]    dule], FileNotFoundException
    [05/16/2018 11:30:01 > d69d33: ERR ]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comm 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:01 > d69d33: ERR ]    ands.ImportModuleCommand
    [05/16/2018 11:30:01 > d69d33: ERR ]  
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ] ConvertFrom-SecureString : The data protection operation was unsuccessful. 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ] This may have been caused by not having the user profile loaded for the 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ] current thread's user context, which may be the case when the thread is 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ] impersonating.
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ] At D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\TQScheduleSyncWebJob\m2gdbfxu.z4g\222.ps1:7 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ] char:9
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ] + $PEnc = ConvertFrom-SecureString -SecureString $POut #??? ??????????  ...
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ] +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ]     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-SecureString], Cr 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ]    yptographicException
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicExcept 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ]    ion,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromSecureStringCommand
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ]  
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ] ConvertTo-SecureString : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'String' because it 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ] is null.
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ] At D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\TQScheduleSyncWebJob\m2gdbfxu.z4g\222.ps1:10 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ] char:16
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ] + $PIn = $PEnc | ConvertTo-SecureString
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ] +                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ]     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [ConvertTo-SecureString], Param 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ]    eterBindingValidationException
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,M 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ]    icrosoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToSecureStringCommand
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ]  
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ] New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "Cannot process 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ] argument because the value of argument "password" is null. Change the value of 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ] argument "password" to a non-null value."
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ] At D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\TQScheduleSyncWebJob\m2gdbfxu.z4g\222.ps1:11 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ] char:10
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ] + $Creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Argume ...
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ] +          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ]     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvoca 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ]    tionException
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.Power 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ]    Shell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
    [05/16/2018 11:30:02 > d69d33: ERR ]  
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ] Connect-MsolService : The term 'Connect-MsolService' is not recognized as the 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ] name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ] spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ] correct and try again.
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ] At D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\TQScheduleSyncWebJob\m2gdbfxu.z4g\222.ps1:14 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ] char:1
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ] + Connect-MsolService -Credential $creds
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ] + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ]     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Connect-MsolService:String) [], 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ]     CommandNotFoundException
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ]  
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ] Connect-AzureAD : The term 'Connect-AzureAD' is not recognized as the name of 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ] a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ] the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ] again.
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ] At D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\TQScheduleSyncWebJob\m2gdbfxu.z4g\222.ps1:15 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ] char:1
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ] + Connect-AzureAD -Credential $creds
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ] + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ]     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Connect-AzureAD:String) [], Com 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ]    mandNotFoundException
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ]  
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ] Get-AzureADUser : The term 'Get-AzureADUser' is not recognized as the name of 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ] a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ] the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ] again.
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ] At D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\TQScheduleSyncWebJob\m2gdbfxu.z4g\222.ps1:20 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ] char:12
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ] + $kwusers = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId 'spo.test@kwpmc.com'
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ] +            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ]     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-AzureADUser:String) [], Com 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:04 > d69d33: ERR ]    mandNotFoundException
    [05/16/2018 11:30:05 > d69d33: ERR ]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
    [05/16/2018 11:30:05 > d69d33: ERR ]  
    [05/16/2018 11:30:05 > d69d33: ERR ] Write-Host : The Win32 internal error "The handle is invalid" 0x6 occurred 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:05 > d69d33: ERR ] while setting character attributes for the console output buffer. Contact 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:05 > d69d33: ERR ] Microsoft Customer Support Services.
    [05/16/2018 11:30:05 > d69d33: ERR ] At D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\TQScheduleSyncWebJob\m2gdbfxu.z4g\222.ps1:49 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:05 > d69d33: ERR ] char:1
    [05/16/2018 11:30:05 > d69d33: ERR ] + Write-Host "?????? ????????????? ?????????"
    [05/16/2018 11:30:05 > d69d33: ERR ] + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    [05/16/2018 11:30:05 > d69d33: ERR ]     + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Write-Host], HostExcep 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:05 > d69d33: ERR ]    tion
    [05/16/2018 11:30:05 > d69d33: ERR ]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetConsoleTextAttribute,Microsoft.PowerShell.Com 
    [05/16/2018 11:30:05 > d69d33: ERR ]    mands.WriteHostCommand
    [05/16/2018 11:30:05 > d69d33: ERR ]  
    [05/16/2018 11:30:05 > d69d33: SYS INFO] Status changed to Success
```

Comment: Wherever you are running this script needs to have the modules installed. Possible duplicate of [MSOnline can't be imported on PowerShell (Connect-MsolService error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018732/msonline-cant-be-imported-on-powershell-connect-msolservice-error)

Comment: Can you perform an `Install-Module MSOnline` ?? Is there a PSSnapin for MSOnline, I am unfamiliar?

Comment: I cant install modules in Azure web job like on my own computer unfortunately.

Comment: @JhonBlack Have you got this issue resolved?
I still face the same issue as yours and didn't get any solutions so far. Please help if you were able to solve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @LeoVarghese, sorry as I remember no.